# How to change height of Mat-Card element in angular material design component

Tags: angular, material-design, angular-material2

I have the following code in angular 5 app. which produces the sequence of mat-card as below image using *ngFor. But the height of all the mat-card is same as the height of first mat-card .

```
         <div fxLayout="row">
          <mat-card *ngFor="let section1 of sections" fxFlex="33" style="margin: 15px;">
               <mat-card-header>
                    <mat-card-title>{{section1}}</mat-card-title>
               </mat-card-header>
               <mat-card-content>
                    <form>
                      <!-----form data goes here ---->
                    </form>

               </mat-card-content>

         </mat-card>

      </div>
```

The result is list of mat card as below, but the problem is height of all mat-card is same as height of first mat card in the loop. Is there any way to make it dynamic based on the content it carries?

[image: Mat-card with same height due to *ngFor]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding a `fxLayoutAlign="start start"` to the container `div` sets the alignment of the cards to what you're looking for. [StackBlitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material2-issue-a2wx8c)

[Flex-Layout fxLayoutAlign API docs](https://github.com/angular/flex-layout/wiki/fxLayoutAlign-API)

[Flex-Layout demo playground](https://tburleson-layouts-demos.firebaseapp.com/#/docs)

Comment: Hey, its working like a charm, Thanks for the Stackblitz demo.

Answer (score 6):

Set `fxFlexAlign="stretch"` to have all mat-card in same height.

Answer (score 2):

The default behavior of flex-layout is to stretch components across the cross axis. In your case this is the height of the cards. This is controlled by the `fxLayoutAlign` property which defaults to `"start stretch"`. To change this, add `fxLayoutAlign="start start"` to your outer `<div fxLayout="row">`. See the [Angular Flex-Layout Demos](https://tburleson-layouts-demos.firebaseapp.com/#/docs) page for more information.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I need this explanation so that I can use the concept in further development.